# How to send Model to _Layout.cshtml (I need to send another model to Index view too)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-layout

I need to send 2 different `Models`, one to `Index view` and another one to `_Layout.cshtml`, how I can do it?

My `HomeController`:

```
[Route("")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HomeViewModel model = new HomeViewModel();
    model.A = _repoA.GetLatest(4);
    model.B = _repoB.GetLatest(4);
    model.C = _repoC.GetLatest(4);
    return View(model);
}
```

I don't like using `ViewBag`, `ViewData` & ..., I'm looking for passing the model in same way as we passing model to `Views`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Razor pass model to layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154407/asp-net-mvc-razor-pass-model-to-layout)

Comment: Why not create a partial view with the model and render it in the layout.

Comment: That's sounds great, but I prefer do it without this solution, is there any way to sending model direct to _layout?

Comment: Use a partial view or child action. Many examples -- See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459390/asp-net-mvc-3-partial-view-in-layout-page), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552502/passing-data-to-a-layout-page), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938837/asp-net-mvc-how-to-have-a-controller-in-shared-view)...

Comment: Please read the question again, I wanna send to both of `index view` & `partial view` !!!

Answer (score 3):

You can place this in your Layout to load a partial each time... Pretty useful for loading in a piece of a dynamic menu or a widget on each page.

Along with this line in your layout you can just do your Index page as you normally would.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("_widget", "Home"); }
```

Comment: We can't use RenderAction in _Layout.cshtml. It leads to recursive call

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to send it along in the ViewBag. I found the best bet was to make an abstract controller:

```
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    protected ApplicationController()
    {
         UserStateViewModel = new UserStateViewModel();
         //Modify the UserStateViewModel here.
         ViewBag["UserStateViewModel"] = UserStateViewModel;
    }

    public UserStateViewModel UserStateViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Then, have all of your controllers inherit from this abstract controller.

In your _Layout.cshtml (or whatever you called it), you'll need to include the following at the top:

```
@{
     var userState = (UserStateViewModel)ViewBag.UserStateViewModel;
}
```

Duplicate but refined from the 2nd answer to [ASP.NET MVC Razor pass model to layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154407/asp-net-mvc-razor-pass-model-to-layout).

Comment: Is there a better way to do this? it seems that it couples your controller to the View. The whole point of the MVC pattern is to be able to decouple.